# "Use of undeclared identifier" - what is wrong with the code?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have just switched from Java to C++, so can someone explain what is wrong with this piece of code:

```
#include "x.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int min(int a,int b,int c){
 return minimum(minimum(a,b),c);
}

int minimum(int a,int b){
  if(a<b) return a;
  return b;
}

int main()
{
  cout<<min(1,2,3)<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler says that `minimum` is undeclared. But why?

P.S. my IDE is Xcode

Comment: Define `int minimum(int a,int b){` before `int min(int a,int b,int c){`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That should be an answer.

Comment: As suggested above, your method `min(a,b,c)` does not know that a method named `minimum(a,b)` exists.

Comment: @zenith Nope! The question should be duped ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minimum` needs to have been declared at the point of the call.

You can move the definition of `minimum` above `min`:

```
int minimum(int a,int b){
  if(a<b) return a;
  return b;
}

int min(int a,int b,int c){
  return minimum(minimum(a,b),c);
}
```

Or you can [*forward-declare*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) `minimum`:

```
int minimum(int a,int b);

int min(int a,int b,int c){
  return minimum(minimum(a,b),c);
}

int minimum(int a,int b){
  if(a<b) return a;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Nice that you are hinting on *and* showing the difference between "declaration" and "definition".

Answer (score 1):

You're using `minimum` before you have declared it.

To declare it before its use in `min`, you could add this before `min`:

```
int minimum(int a, int b);
```

This is a *declaration*.

You could also move the whole *definition* of `minimum` before `min`.